# How do i write an ipo chart based on the fibonacci method?

Tags: c, fibonacci, pseudocode

This is what I wrote up based on the Fibonacci method but when it came down to doing an IPO chart around it I seem to get stuck in the processing phase. I know this might be something that should be easy to do but I'm relatively new to this.

This is an example of another IPO chart:

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
  int n,t=0,tt=1,b=0,i;
  printf("Enter sequence limit: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Fibonacci sequence: %d %d",t,tt);
  b=t+tt;
  for (i=1;b<=n;i++)
  {
    printf(" %d ",b);
    t=tt;
    tt=b;
    b=t+tt;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `ipo`?.

Comment: @coderredoc Probably [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPO_model).

Comment: @user202729.: Formal words - too formal.

Comment: `for (i=1;b<=n;i++)` -> `for (i=1;i<=n;i++)` Sequence upto length `n` right?

Comment: intellectual property ownership?

Answer (score 1):

The condition in loop was incorrect:

```
for (i=1;b<=n;i++)
```

You need `i<=n` not `b<=n`, since you need `n` sequence numbers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
  int n,t=0,tt=1,b=0,i;

  printf("Enter sequence limit: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  printf("Fibonacci sequence: %d %d\n",t,tt);

  b=t+tt;
  for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
  {
    printf(" %d ",b);
    t=tt;
    tt=b;
    b=t+tt;
  }
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter sequence limit: 10                                                                                                                     
Fibonacci sequence: 0 1                                                                                                                      
 1  2  3  5  8  13  21  34  55  89
```

In the light of new information regarding IPO:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    float weekly_pay;
    float raise;
    float weekly_raise;
    float new_weekly_pay;

    // 1. current weekly pay:
    printf("Enter weekly_pay: \n");
    scanf("%f",&weekly_pay);

    // 2. raise rate
    printf("Enter raise: \n");
    scanf("%f",&raise);

    // 3. weekly raise
    weekly_raise = weekly_pay * raise;

    // 4.new weekly pay
    new_weekly_pay = weekly_pay + weekly_raise;

    // 5. Output:
    printf("New weekly pay is: %8.2f \n", new_weekly_pay);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
100.0
0.01
```

Output:

```
New weekly pay is:   101.00
```

Comment: The loop will terminate just fine. Yes, `0 < n` will always be true, but `b` won't always be 0. It will increase (by increasing amount) at each iteration of the loop until it exceeds `n`.

Comment: @sg7 the limit is supposed to stop it from calculating beyond the n...so if n=10 then it can only calculate as far as 10 and nothing beyond

Comment: @konkroo OK! Then there is nothing wrong in your original algorithm! I understood is differently as I described. So, the problem is located somewhere else, not in the presented code.

Comment: @sg7 an ipo is input-process-output its like a description of what goes on with the program e.g. http://images.slideplayer.com/35/10466918/slides/slide_17.jpg i wanna know how to put this program like that

Comment: @usr2564301 Thank you! That should clarify the question.